# Configuring Solr in Alfresco - meaning of alfresco.lag property?

Tags: solr, alfresco

I recently noticed a problem due to the eventual consistency of Solr indexing in Alfresco. The problem is that files are not appearing in searches that are performed immediately after the file is uploaded.  I have been looking at the configuration properties to see if I can improve the performance (reduce the latency).

It looks as though changing the `alfresco.cron` property would help, so Solr would check for repository updates more freqently, rather than the default 15 seconds `alfresco.cron=0/15 * * * * ? *`

However, I'm unclear what the `alfresco.lag=1000` property does, or what its purpose is. The [Alfresco wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_And_SOLR) says:

> Each "track" will run until the time when it starts - less this lag

which makes no sense to me - what is a "track", and how can something run until the time it starts?

The [Alfresco 4.1 docs](http://docs.alfresco.com), and [this article](http://www.ixxus.com/blog/2012/06/getting-going-with-solr-alfresco-4/) say:

> This specifies the tracker property to set the time (in seconds) that
>   the Solr full text index is currently behind the repository updates.

and

> Solr indexes are updated in the background. This is the time (in
>   seconds) this Solr index is currently behind the repository updates.

But I'm none the wiser - does this mean that Solr could be 1000 seconds behind the repository (plus 15 seconds due to the cron interval)? This seems a *huge* lag, if so - I am hoping for a few seconds maximum.

What is the practical effect of adjusting `alfresco.lag` (what would happen if I greatly reduced it or set it to zero, for example)? The example value in the Alfresco docs is 0 seconds, but the default in the config file is 1000 - what are the tradeoffs of adjusting this property?

**Update:** I suspect the units are mis-documented, and are actually milliseconds not seconds, since `org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker` has the following code:

```
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    state.timeToStopIndexing = startTime - lag;
```

Answer (score 1):

afaik alfresco.lag=1000 means that the Solr Tracker will try to index all transactions that have been committed at least a second ago.
I guess setting to 0 may have some side-effects, e.g. if your SOLR is running on a different machine & time service is not 100% in sync.

Comment: Thanks - but if a transaction has been committed, is there any reason not to always index it immediately, though?

Comment: it's a conceptually thing: pull vs. push. Solr tracks the txn in the repo & pulls the relevant data, also called eventually consistency.